# How to execute pkg.refresh_db in a salt state?

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following sls file:

```
python:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - python2_x64
```

How can I edit this file to make sure `pkg.refresh_db` is executed prior to attepting to install Python?

I can manually run the refresh like this: `salt -G 'os:windows' pkg.refresh_db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pkg:
module.run:
  - name: pkg.refresh_db

python:
pkg.installed:
  - pkgs:
    - python2_x64
```

Comment: or just `pkg.refresh_db: module.run` (second keyword on next line, indented).

Answer (score 0):

Add `refresh: True` to the `pkg.installed` state:

```
python:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - python2_x64
    - refresh: True
```

or even shorter:

```
python2_x64:
  pkg.installed:
    - refresh: True
```